# this command works, but when I use it in a for loop is does not

Tags: scripting, osx

I am trying to go through all of the users in the User folder and print out how many files they each have in their home directories. From experimentation when I'm in the Users directory

```
    ls ./<someusername> | wc -l
```

this command prints out what I want. When i use it in the for loop...

```
    for f in ./*; do ls ./* | wc -l $f; done
```

it gives me

```
    wc: ./user1: read: Is a directory
    wc: ./user2: read: Is a directory
    wc: ./user3: read: Is a directory
    wc: ./user4: read: Is a directory
```

and not the number or folders for the user. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it, I've been troubleshooting for some time.

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in ./*; do ls ./* | wc -l $f; done
```

This sets `f` to all the filenames in the current directory (`./*`) in turn. For each of them, it runs `ls` again with all the file names in the current directory, piping the output to `wc -l $f`. Now, `wc -l` counts the lines in the files given as arguments, and looks at stdin only if none are. So the pipe is ignored by `wc` here and it tries to read whatever file is named in `f`, failing when it's a directory.

I suspect what you want is something like this

```
for f in ./* ; do ls "$f" | wc -l ; done
```

Which would run `ls` on on the directory named in `f`, and then count the lines in that. But `ls` might ignore files whose names start with a dot (`ls -A` lists them too, skipping `.` and `..`), and the glob might match regular files too (if you have any in that main directory).

But you don't really need `ls` or `wc` at all. OS X should have Bash, where this should work:

```
shopt -s dotglob       # '*' matches files with a leading dot, too
for f in ./*/ ; do     # trailing slash only picks directories
    set -- "$f"/*      # fill the positional params with the filenames in the dir 
    echo "$f $#"       # print the directory name and number of params/files
done
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the quick response! This totally works! I am not familiar with the shopt bash script. I'll be sure to look up more about it. During my researching prior to this post I found that many people ask about general commands in use with filters such as awk and grep and almost ALWAYS theres a bash script that is more appropriate. Once again thanks for the timely response!

Comment: @Jay, Bash has a number of useful switches settable via `shopt`, esp. the glob-related ones are often useful: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html